# How to programatically set Task Scheduler security options?

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I am trying the set the 'Run whether user is logged on or not' option in the Security Options section of the Windows Task Scheduler.

[image]

I am using the [Task Scheduler Managed Wrapper](http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/).

I have tried this:

```
using (TaskService taskService = new TaskService())
{
    try
    {
        TaskDefinition taskDefinition = taskService.NewTask();
        ...some triggers...
        taskDefinition.Actions.Add(new ExecAction( "iexplore.exe", vmsTask.Args, "C:\\"));
        taskDefinition.Principal.LogonType = TaskLogonType.None;
        taskService.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition("Task Name", taskDefinition);
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    { }
}
```

This line throws an exception: `taskDefinition.Principal.LogonType = TaskLogonType.None;`

The Exception is:

> Value does not fall within the expected range.

What is the correct way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `TaskLogonType.None` means

> The logon method is not specified.

Obviously, that's not what you want. You probably want either `Password` or `ServiceAccount` ("Run only when user is logged on" is ~`InteractiveToken`).

Answer (score 0):

I did this and it worked:

```
using (var tasksrvc = GetTaskService(hostName, userName, password))
{
      tasksrvc.AddTask(
               taskName,
               QuickTriggerType.Daily,
               taskFolderPath,
               null,
               "UserName",
               "Password",
               TaskLogonType.Password);                    
}
```